# Non-GUI Emacs with cscope

Tags: emacs, cscope

So, i'm running emacs over a crappy ssh connection and I have it set up to use cscope. I can not use X because of this...hence I'm running emacs inside putty. However, when I search for something with cscope and it opens up the other buffer, I can not
follow the links where cscope tells me which file and line number the item is on. When I go t a line number and hit enter, emacs tells me 'buffer is read-only' (it is trying to actually put in a new line instead of following the link). anyone know how I can follow those links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about cscope for sure - but you should be able to find out the appropriate key binding by doing a "Ctrl-h m" in the buffer with all the links. This should open another buffer showing you help/key bindings on all the active modes.

E.g. if you do the same thing in a grep result buffer it indicates the key binding "C-c C-c    compile-goto-error" which is used to open file at the grep line number (so it may be the same keys for cscope).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I'm pressing *<space>* key on the cscope result line.  It shows the code in the other frame, although it doesn't position the cursor there.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this line in xcscope.el fixed the problem on my computer.

```
-(define-key cscope-list-entry-keymap [return] 'cscope-select-entry-other-window)
+(define-key cscope-list-entry-keymap (kbd "RET") 'cscope-select-entry-other-window)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use cscope with Tramp mode?  I'm not familiar with cscope, but I've had great results using tramp mode to read/write files remotely over an SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `GNU find version 4.2` and above supports `-L` to follow symbolic links. Hence,

```
find -L . -name *.[ch] > cscope.files
cscope -b -R -q -i cscope.files
```

might work well

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround. Just type 'o' to select what you want. It means cscope-select-entry-one-window :)